# Coalgebraic description of converse of a binary relation on a set

Tags: category-theory, relations, coalgebras

A binary relation on a set is a coalgebra for the powerset endofunctor on the category of sets. In this coalgebraic setting, how do you construct or characterize the coalgebra which represents the converse relation of a given relation?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\mathcal{P} : \mathtt{Set} \to \mathtt{Set}$ is the power set endofunctor. Then, $\mathcal{P}$-coalgebras are in bijective correspondence with binary relations.

Let $r : X \to \mathcal{P}(X)$ is a $\mathcal{P}$-coalgebra. Define the binary relation
$$R = \big\{ (x,y) \;\big|\; y \in r(x) \subset X \big\} \subset X \times X.$$
Conversely, given any binary relation $S \subset X \times X$, construct the $\mathcal{P}$-coalgebra $s : X \to \mathcal{P}(X)$ by $$s(x) = \{ y \in X \,|\, (x,y) \in S\}.$$

Clearly, these are inverses to each other.

Comment: Yes, given $r$ we can unpack it to $R$ and then construct $s$. But, is there some way to relate $r$ to $s$ that is more category-theoretic? Maybe we can only go from $X \to (Y \to 2) $ to $(X \times Y) \to 2$ to $(Y \times X) \to 2$ etc?

Answer (score 0):

(to answer my own question) I was looking for something like this:

Let $\gamma: X \to PY$ represent the relation $R \subseteq X \times Y$ where $P$ is the covariant powerset functor. Let $P^{\!\ast}$ be the contravariant powerset functor.
Then the coalgebra representing the converse $\breve{R} \subseteq Y \times X$
is the following composite.
$$Y \stackrel{\{.\}}{\to} PY \stackrel{\subseteq}{\to} P^{\!\ast} PY \stackrel{P^{\!\ast} \gamma}{\to} P^{\!\ast} X = PX$$